# hp keyboard rt7h10 hotkeys not working

Tags: windows, drivers, keyboard, desktop-computer, hotkeys

i recently bought an hp rt7h10 keyboard, and i cant find the driver for it. Since the search, internet, email, media controls are not working, i was wondering -could someone please give me a driver link for this?
thanks, cappypi

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Go to this page and use the Detect Your product button, see if it can find drivers>>>>>https://support.hp.com/ie-en/drivers/products

Comment: thanks, but it says it cant find my device